# Modal Dialog Jquery not working on Chrome and internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using Jquery plugin modal Dialog in my MVC application but it is not working when i scroll down the screen and at the it only shows gray screen but in other browsers it is working fine.
First screen shot is from Google Chrome and 2nd is taken by Mozilla

[image: Screen shot in google chrome]

[image: screen shot in Mozilla]

```
<div class="modal carrier-modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bind="modal: {}, modalVisible: isEditingProducts">
<section>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h1>
                    <span>Carrier Products</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <form data-bind="with: carrierForProductsEdit, submit: saveProducts" class="form">
                <div class="modal-body">                   
                    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'carrierProductItem', foreach: CarrierProducts }">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                    <span class="textor">or</span>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="simple">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Question Updated

Comment: While you are trying in chrome, are you getting any error on firebug console?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL `firebug` works on Chrome?

Comment: There is no error on Firebug Console...

Comment: @Anup right click and "inspect element"

Comment: @ZaidIqbal There will be no error....coz its a `css` issue.

Comment: @Anup i have checked the css but i couldn't understand where i am strucked..Can you help

Comment: Select the modal box div in `Inspect element` & try increasing its height.

Comment: already tried but failed!!!

Comment: @Anup I think Error is not in the height of Modal Dialog. Error resides in the windows scroller because when i scroll down than this error occurred otherwise when i am at top(not scroll down) it works perfect. What you say?

Comment: If the project is online...you can give me link...

Comment: @Anup are you able to login to the system?

Comment: ok wait...i will check

Comment: Its showing `The user name or password provided is incorrect.`

Comment: `The Email address field is not a valid e-mail address.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46672/discussion-between-zaid-iqbal-and-anup)

Comment: @Anup are you login now???

Comment: There are 4 errors shown on ur console.

Comment: But these are not related to this error... they are like image error or something else but no related to this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, its difficult to tell what is exact problem in ur case.

```
<div style="min-height: 500px!important;" class="modal carrier-modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bind="modal: {}, modalVisible: isEditingProducts">
     ....
</div>
```